# Using Oracle Path Expressions on JSON arrays

Tags: oracle12c, jsonpath

I am attempting to write a simple query with path expressions against an Oracle JSON data structure that will return the Student Name and the the name of their CS220 teacher (if they are taking that class).

The JSON:

```
{
  'studentName': 'John Smith',
  'classes': [
    {
      'className': 'CS115',
      'teacherName': 'Sally Wilson'
    },
    {
      'className': 'CS220',
      'teacherName': 'Jason Wu'
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected Output

```
Student Name      Professor
John Smith        Jason Wu
Jane Doe                             << Not taking CS220
Ajay Kumar        Robert Kroll
```

The query I would hope to write:

```
Select 
    jsonfield.studentName,
    jsonfield.classes.<some path expression to find the CS220 professor here>
from mytable
```

The only solution I have found is to project out the nested 'classes' into a table and join that to the query above to get the professor.  I would have thought that Oracle's json path implementation would be able to solve this without the overhead/complexity of a second query.

Comment: Release 1 or release 2? In the latter you can probably do this with `json_table()` and a nested path with a filter...

Comment: On release 1 currently but moving to release 2 shortly.  Even with release 2 I don't see a path expression that lets me describe this.  The challenge with a 'single json_table / filter by classname = CS220' solution is that 'Jane Doe' would drop out of the result.

Comment: I was thinking of something like `nested path '$.classes[*]?(@.className=="CS220")'` rather than a where-clause filter, but as that isn't valid in release 1 that doesn't help much...

Comment: I'm good with a Release 2 solution.  What I was looking for was a path that resolved to the professor's name qualified by a peer classname='CS220'.

Comment: The path expression I'd like to describe would be something like: $.classes[(@.className='CS220')].teacherName which resolved to the teacherName for the first CS220 class.  This is how I would have described the query in xpath.

Comment: That's pretty much what I used for my 12cR2 solution/guess; except with a question mark and `==`, and no squares brackets; which is based on [the examples in the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/ADJSN/json-path-expressions.htm#ADXDB6372). I'll be ineterested to see if that's anywhere close to right...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 12cR1 you could do something like:

```
select jt.studentname,
  max(case when jt.classname = 'CS220' then jt.teachername end) as teachername
from mytable mt
cross join json_table (
  mt.jsonfield,
  '$'
  columns (
    studentname varchar2(30) path '$.studentName',
    nested path '$.classes[*]' columns (
      classname varchar2(30) path '$.className',
      teachername varchar2(30) path '$.teacherName'
    )
  )
) jt
group by jt.studentname;
```

The `json_table()` splits the JSON into relational columns; the `nested path` means you get one row per class (per student), with the relevant class names and teacher names.

The select list then uses a case expression to change the teacher name to null for any other classes - so John Smith gets one row with CS220 and Jason Wu, and one row with CS115 and null. Aggregating that with `max()` collapses those so all the irrelevant teachers are ignored.

With some expanded sample data:

```
create table mytable (jsonfield clob check (jsonfield is json));
insert into mytable a(jsonfield) values (q'#{
  'studentName': 'John Smith',
  'classes': [
    {
      'className': 'CS115',
      'teacherName': 'Sally Wilson'
    },
    {
      'className': 'CS220',
      'teacherName': 'Jason Wu'
    }
  ]
}#');
insert into mytable a(jsonfield) values (q'#{
  'studentName': 'Jane Doe',
  'classes': [
    {
      'className': 'CS115',
      'teacherName': 'Sally Wilson'
    }
  ]
}#');
insert into mytable a(jsonfield) values (q'#{
  'studentName': 'Ajay Kumar',
  'classes': [
    {
      'className': 'CS220',
      'teacherName': 'Robert Kroll'
    }
  ]
}#');
```

the basic `json_table()` call gets:

```
select jt.*,
  case when jt.classname = 'CS220' then jt.teachername end as adjusted_teachername
from mytable mt
cross join json_table (
  mt.jsonfield,
  '$'
  columns (
    studentname varchar2(30) path '$.studentName',
    nested path '$.classes[*]' columns (
      classname varchar2(30) path '$.className',
      teachername varchar2(30) path '$.teacherName'
    )
  )
) jt;

STUDENTNAME                    CLASSNAME                      TEACHERNAME                    ADJUSTED_TEACHERNAME         
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------
John Smith                     CS115                          Sally Wilson                                                 
John Smith                     CS220                          Jason Wu                       Jason Wu                      
Jane Doe                       CS115                          Sally Wilson                                                 
Ajay Kumar                     CS220                          Robert Kroll                   Robert Kroll
```

Adding the aggregation step gets:

```
select jt.studentname,
  max(case when jt.classname = 'CS220' then jt.teachername end) as teachername
from mytable mt
cross join json_table (
  mt.jsonfield,
  '$'
  columns (
    studentname varchar2(30) path '$.studentName',
    nested path '$.classes[*]' columns (
      classname varchar2(30) path '$.className',
      teachername varchar2(30) path '$.teacherName'
    )
  )
) jt
group by jt.studentname;

STUDENTNAME                    TEACHERNAME                  
------------------------------ ------------------------------
John Smith                     Jason Wu                      
Jane Doe                                                     
Ajay Kumar                     Robert Kroll
```

---

In 12cR2 I *<strike>think</strike> thought* you might be able to do something like this instead, with a filter inside the JSON path (which isn't allowed in 12cR1):

```
select jt.*
from mytable mt
cross join json_table (
  mt.jsonfield,
  '$'
  columns (
    studentname varchar2(30) path '$.studentName',
    nested path '$.classes[*]?(@.className=="CS220")' columns (
      teachername varchar2(30) path '$.teacherName'
    )
  )
) jt;
```

<strike>... but I don't have a suitable DB to test that against.</strike>

... but it turns out that gets "ORA-40553: path expression with predicates not supported in this operation" and "Only JSON_EXISTS supports predicates".

Comment: Agreed Alex that's the way to solve it with a join.  What does not feel right to me is that the original query already accesses all of the data needed to satisfy the results but because Oracle's path expression syntax is incomplete, a second query of the same records is needed to from the join.  I was hoping it was a gap in my understanding of path expressions. Release 3 perhaps?

Comment: It isn’t doing a second  query though; the `jsonfield` value is exploded by the `json_table()`  but it doesn’t join back to the original table again. The cross join is the same mechanism used for `XMLTable()`. This may be more efficient than multiple `json_query()` calls (which dot notation would do anyway, I believe).

Comment: Looks like my 12cR2 guess isn't right; gets ORA-40553, that syntax only seems to be allowed in `json_exists()` calls. The other version still works of course.

Comment: The Release 1 solution worked well and the query plan confirmed that there is no additional I/O joining to the json_table.  Thanks again.